# CSS 'transform: scale()' property doesn't work on iOS Safari and iOS Chrome too

Tags: android, html, ios, css

I use my website a css animation, but it doesn't work in iOS based Safari and Chrome.

HTML:

```
...
<p>
   <a href="mywebsite.hu/something1.php">
      <img src="picture1.jpg" class="kep" >
   </a>
   <a href="mywebsite.hu/something2.php">
      <img src="picture2.jpg" class="kep" >
   </a>
   <a href="mywebsite.hu/something3.php">
      <img src="picture3.jpg" class="kep" >
   </a>
</p>
...
```

CSS:

```
img.kep{
   transition: transform.1s linear;
   -moz-transition: transform.1s linear;
   -webkit-transition: transform.1s linear;
}
img.kep:hover{
   transform: scale(1.04);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.04);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.04);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.04);
}
```

It works in windows(IE, Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi, Safari), android(Chrome, default Samsung Galaxy browser).
But in iPad2 with iOS 9.2.1(Safari, Chrome) doesn't works!

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should always include the non-prefixed property last in the list. `transition` and `transform` should be below all the prefixed versions.

So if it's supported, it's used, over a potentially old prefixed version.

Second, you're only transitioning `transform`. So `-webkit-transform` isn't going to get transformed. You're probably best off just transitioning `all`

Third, you haven't got a space between `transform` and `.1s`. Should be a space.

Comment: So I use this -->

img.kep{
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s linear;
 transition: -ms-transform 1s linear;
 transition: transform 1s linear;
}

or this -->

img.kep{
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s linear;
 -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s linear;
 transition: transform 1s linear;
}

or something else ?

Comment: transition:all 1s linear; < this is the shorthand of what you just put. Providing you're not changing any other animatable properties on the same element, that you don't want animating.

Comment: Have you got an example link I can try it on myself?

Comment: Yeah. This : allatorvoscsurgo.hu/galeria

Comment: This is a css that I used now: img.kep {
      -webkit-transition:all 0.1s linear;
      -moz-transition:all 0.1s linear;
      transition:all 0.1s linear;
}
img.kep:hover {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.04);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.04);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.04);
      transform: scale(1.04);
}
img.kep:active {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.96);
      -moz-transform: scale(0.96);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.96);
      transform: scale(0.96);
}

Comment: Ah, of course. It's because you're triggering the hover event, on an element which typically wouldn't have one by default. iOS probably isn't sure what to do.

I would try perhaps adding :focus, as well as :hover. If that doesn't work, you could try shifting the animation onto the parent `<a>` tag. That should fix it. Although it won't be quite the same feel on iOS, as you won't be able to hover off. Also, depending what you're planning to do when that `<a>` is clicked, you might not see the hover.

Comment: I'm trying this solution a.s.a.p! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Now sometimes work on iOS Safari and Chrome :D